# Microsoft Teams Side-Loaded App - Multiple "conversationUpdate" Events Firing

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

This might just be me misunderstanding something, but I'm working on some welcome message logic, and it's firing twice. I'm already doing a foreach to check who is being added to the conversation, because I know I'll be notified, even in this 1-1, of both user + bot joining, something like this:

```
    foreach (var member in membersAdded)
    {
        if (member.Id == turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id) 
        {
           await SendWelcomeMessage(turnContext);
           break;
        }
   }
```

The problem, however, is that I'm getting two ***completely duplicated*** "conversationUpdate" events being fired. This is a 1-1 chat, and I'm getting the following (redacted) **both times**:

```
    "membersAdded": [
        {
            "id": "29:...",
            "aadObjectId": "[guid]"
        },
        {
            "id": "28:..."
        }
    ],
    "type": "conversationUpdate",
    "timestamp": "...",
    "id": "f:guid",
...
```

the only thing that changes is the message id, but aside from that, I get both entries in membersAdded both times. I know I should get notified of both members being added to this 1-1, but surely I should get **either** two entries in membersAdded **or** two "conversationUpdate" events? Right now I'm getting, basically, 2x2.

Is the only solution to track conversation state, to determine if I've "Welcomed" this user before in this same 1-1 conversation? Even if I do try that, I'm worried I'll end up with two state entries (e.g. two duplicates in the database) because of thread timing issues (one could still be creating the database entry for the conversation, and there's no way to differentiate the conversationUpdates right now).

What am I missing?

Perhaps it's relevant that this is a side-loaded custom app? Also, this only happens the very first time I install the app - if I uninstall and re-install, I just get 1 notification.

Comment: We have identified this issue and created a bug. Currently we are tracking it internally and there is no ETA as of now.

Comment: Thanks @Subhasish-MSFT, glad to know it's logged and being addressed, and also that I'm not just going crazy! Incidentally, a "welcome" message is listed as a pre-requisite to listing an app in the store, so perhaps let the verification team know that there's currently an issue.

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT Is this an issue with just the side-loaded apps or even the ones published to the store?

Comment: @Rahim, We have reproduced it only for side-loaded apps.

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT I don't think so. I installed the Trello bot recently and I got greeted twice by the bot. Is there an issue ID or link where we can track this?